# How to stop jQuery tooltip from hiding so I can click on a hyperlink

Tags: javascript, jquery, tooltip, jquery-ui-tooltip

I'm looking to use jQuery tooltip to show a breakdown for a certain number in a table, with some hyperlinks within the tooltip content.  It displays properly but when I mouse out of the tooltip trigger element the tooltip obviously hides.

Here's my code..

```
$(document).tooltip({
    items: '.icon-info-sign',
    content: function () {
        var tooltipTrigger = $(this);
        return $(tooltipTrigger).siblings('.tooltip-content').html();
    }
});
```

Comment: This is a known issue they haven't really made a decision on. I believe there is a link to their forums with a temp fix. [**See issue Ticket**](http://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/8782) There is a link to an expanded version of ToolTip called [`pToolTip`](http://jsfiddle.net/BgDxs/2/) on that ticket page

Comment: I would recommend creating your own tooltip for it.

Comment: Ah I see, just read through the issue ticket and can understand why it hasn't been implemented.  I'll have a play with pToolTip thanks